# Django + NGINX only serving some static files

Tags: django, nginx, static

This is probably the millionth django+nginx post, but since I didn't find an answer after more than 5 hours here it goes:

My issue is that not all static files get served, only some. The whole thing runs inside Docker where I run

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput;
RUN python manage.py makemigrations;
RUN python manage.py migrate;
```

on each start, but it does not serve my new .js and .css files although they are in the same directories as the old ones.

I also see the message:

```
132 static files copied to '/static'.
```

and above that is the list of files being copied there, including the new ones.

Project Structure:

```
/djangoapp
  /app
    /static
      /css
      /js
  /django
  /Dockerfile
/docker-compose
```

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static'
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /static; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout   3600;
        proxy_send_timeout      3600;
        proxy_read_timeout      3600;
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

Why aren't all static files being served?

EDIT:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.4-onbuild
RUN mkdir /config;
RUN mkdir /src;  
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src 
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput;
RUN python manage.py makemigrations;
RUN python manage.py migrate;
RUN chmod 775 -R /static
#this shows that the new files reside with the others in  the same directory
RUN ls -R /static/ 
CMD gunicorn WebInterface.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 3600
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version : '3'

services:
web:
  build: ./WebInterface
  container_name: WebDocker
  volumes: 
    - static-content:/static
  expose:
    - "80"

nginx:
  image: nginx:1.12.2
  container_name: NGINXDocker
  ports:
  - "8000:8000"
  volumes:
    - ./WebInterface:/src
    - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    - static-content:/static
  depends_on:
    - web

volumes:
  static-content:
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and discovered that even though I was copying new files into an image, Docker would keep using the previous files as was using an old volume. I needed to stop the containers, blow away the containers and volumes with `docker-compose -f -a web nginx` and then bring the containers and volumes back up with `docker-compose up -d web nginx`

Comment: @WillKeeling I even delete all my containers and images multiple times to no avail :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the additional info I think I know what's going on.
You run your python script to generate static files (which I assume it does) on build. On run, you mount the directory, so it will overwrite everything in the static directory.
Either don't mount it or add the scripts

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput;
python manage.py makemigrations;
python manage.py migrate;
```

in the entrypoint (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

<s>Also, the mounting of static into the nginx container doesn't do anything since you are only reverse proxying into the django container and not giving a root path</s>. Or if it does work by some coincident, I'm not sure if it would get the newly generated files on startup.

Hope this helps, had a lot of fun with that stuff when I started with docker...

Comment: Made an edit, but to answer your questions: 1. If I didnt mount it the collectstatic, makemigrations commands etc. would throw an error. 2. yes, they are with the other files 3. added more information

Comment: Thanks it worked. I will update my own answer here to make it more clear. Tbh I still quite don't understand why it works. Also I need to do '- static-content:/static' for in both to share that volume with nginx, otherthise it won't have access to those files

Comment: Good to hear. You have to differentiate very much between run and build time. The mount happens on run, that's why it is overwriting whats in the image.
With the nginx static  thing, I guess there is no routing inside the web container? (depends on the framework/application you are using) you can check by curl {docker-host-of-web}/static. There is probably nothing. Right now nginx is accessing the /static directory you mount to. I recommend you fix this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for now is to create the static folder on my local machine and then transfer the files to the desired position inside docker-compose.

When I find a real solution, on why collect static is not working within docker I will update this

**Edit: Solution provided by LevinM**

updated the Dockerfile (This only provides the image and installs python libraries from requirements.txt due to the 'onbuild' parameter):

```
FROM python:3.6.4-onbuild
```

updated docker-compose.yml:

```
version : '3'

services:

    web:
      build: ./WebInterface
      entrypoint: bash -c  "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&  python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate &&  gunicorn WebInterface.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 3600";
      container_name: WebDocker
      volumes: 
        - ./WebInterface:/src
        - static-content:/static
      expose:
        - "80"
    
    nginx:
      image: nginx:1.12.2
      container_name: NGINXDocker
      ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      volumes:
        - ./WebInterface:/src
        - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        - static-content:/static
      depends_on:
        - web

volumes:
  static-content:
```